# Pronunciation difference between 绿, and 陆。

Tags: difference, pronunciation

你们怎么样 ？

I cannot find the right pronunciation for words like 绿. The pronunciation of 绿 in my mind is too similar to words like, 陆 。

Help me differenciate between the two and study more about that particular 绿 entonation, please.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I`m sorry if this is a duplicate question, i could not find something similar enough.

Comment: 陆 as in `lu`bricant but in fourth tone. 绿 sounds like /lʒ/ in fourth tone.

Comment: @imkzh How is /lʒ/ a valid syllable in Chinese...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial in 綠 (*lü*) and 陸 (*lu*) are the same. You are essentially asking how to pronounce the pinyin *ü* and *u*.

1. Silently, round your lips tightly into a small circle (but don't close it completely). Within the oral cavity, place the tip of your tongue at the very front. Now make some sound from your vocal cords. You are now pronouncing the close **front** rounded vowel /y/, or the pinyin *ü*.
2. Continue to make sound, but now slowly move the tip of your tongue backwards, until you hear the familiar /u/, or the pinyin *u*. This is the close **back** rounded vowel.
3. You may draw reference from other languages that you are familiar with when learning how to pronounce a certain vowel in a new language. (More examples of [/y/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel#Occurrence) and [/u/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_back_rounded_vowel#Occurrence) from Wikipedia)

   |  | /y/, *ü* | /u/, *u* |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | English | f**ew** [fj**yː**] (multicultural London) | b**oo**t [b**u̟ː**t] |
   | German | **ü**ber [ˈ**yː**bɐ] 'over' | F**u**ß [f**uː**s] 'foot' |
   | French | t**u** [t̪**y**] 'you' | **où** [**u**] 'where' |

   I think the difference in German (ü vs u) is best understood. It is even reflected in its spelling.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the ü and u.

绿, make the tongue tip in V or U shape, then push the air out of your mouth.

陆, is just like oo in look.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Zhuyin, this will help. Otherwise, you can figure out how to pronounce by recognizing the example words that share the same sound, and tune (4th).

- 绿 [image] - 法"律", 顧"虑", 利"率", 過"滤"
- 陸 [image] - 道"路", 甘"露", 小"鹿", 忙"碌", 賄"赂"

I don't think you have a problem pronouncing 陸 which has the same pronunciation as "Lou" in English, or the last syllable of "Waterloo".

The difficulty in pronouncing 绿 is due to the lacking of similar pronunciation in your native language. I suggest practicing the pronunciation of the word 玉, which is the ending sound of 绿 [image]. You'll realize that it is quite different from 陸 [image] that ends in the sound of "oo".